# How to correctly cite ASCII (Public table)? Do I need to cite it?

Tags: citations, computer-science, public-domain

I have included ASCII table in my paper research, but I'm not sure how can I correctly cite it. I have seen many papers not including any citation while others mention any random website that has the table.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ASCII standard is set out in [this document](http://worldpowersystems.com/J/codes/X3.4-1963/), so you should cite it directly.

Comment: Appreciate the help Mr.Bill Barth